# Standalone jenkins.war vs configuration persistence?

Tags: java, jenkins, jetty

Due to limited rights I can only use Jenkins by running

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

This deploys Jenkins to a built in Jetty server.

However when I restart Jenkins, the configuration will eventually get lost. Is there any way to keep that data persistent without deploying Jenkins to a regular application server?

Note: I do not have root privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Jenkins installation stores all the logs, config details, build artifacts under `~/.jenkins` directory. So you can archive this directory and replace it when you restart the service.

In case if you have customized the home directory then archive the customized home directory.

This link may help you to find the home directory.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins